# Pip is broken after error uninstalling toml package, what steps can I take to reset it?

Tags: python, linux, pip

I was uninstalling my locally installed pylint package and its dependencies not required by other packages via pip, and in the process seem to have completely sunk pip on my system (Manjaro Linux), particularly while uninstalling the toml package.

toml was one of the dependencies for pylint reported by `pip show pylint`, and when `pip show toml` reported no packages required it, I ran `pip uninstall toml`, and, falsely assuming it was a local package, forgot to prefix the command with `sudo`, which lead to the exception:

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 788, in move
    os.rename(src, real_dst)
OSError: [Errno 18] Invalid cross-device link: '/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/toml' -> '/tmp/pip-uninstall-hnohl3wr'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/base_command.py", line 188, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/uninstall.py", line 85, in run
    uninstall_pathset = req.uninstall(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 676, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset.remove(auto_confirm, verbose)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 394, in remove
    moved.stash(path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_uninstall.py", line 283, in stash
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/utils/misc.py", line 349, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 800, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 715, in rmtree
    _rmtree_safe_fd(fd, path, onerror)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 672, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    onerror(os.unlink, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/shutil.py", line 670, in _rmtree_safe_fd
    os.unlink(entry.name, dir_fd=topfd)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'decoder.py'
```

I then just ran `sudo pip uninstall toml` which reported success. However, all subsequent attempts at installing, uninstalling or upgrading any packages via pip, currently on my system or not, have been met with the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/pip", line 33, in <module>
    sys.exit(load_entry_point('pip==20.1.1', 'console_scripts', 'pip')())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 73, in main
    command = create_command(cmd_name, isolated=("--isolated" in cmd_args))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/__init__.py", line 104, in create_command
    module = importlib.import_module(module_path)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/commands/install.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.req_command import RequirementCommand, with_cleanup
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/cli/req_command.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.req.constructors import (
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/__init__.py", line 12, in <module>
    from .req_install import InstallRequirement
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/req/req_install.py", line 31, in <module>
    from pip._internal.pyproject import load_pyproject_toml, make_pyproject_path
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_internal/pyproject.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pip._vendor import six, toml
ImportError: cannot import name 'toml' from 'pip._vendor' (/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip/_vendor/__init__.py)
```

The same error is also reported with `pip freeze` and `pip list`.

Was toml actually a major `pip` dependency but just not being reported as such? Is anyone familiar enough with the architecture of pip to know how I might clean up my installation? I would be okay removing all pip packages and just trying to reset my system if I could avoid borking it by removing python scripts and libs needed by the OS, but seeing as the `pip list/freeze` and `pip uninstall` commands aren't working anymore I'm not sure how I would do so. Any help here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like that's the system `pip`, so you could try reinstalling it with your package manager (`apt`, 'yum`, 'dnf', `zypper` or whatever).  You may have to specify that it's `pip` for `python3`.

Comment: Yes, removing and reinstalling with pacman worked. It does look like toml was probably baked into pip itself. I guess just going by the reported dependencies of `pip show` is sometimes not safe!

Comment: thats why you should not install stuff globally with pip. User --user flag or something like venv.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pip does require toml as a potential means of reading project build-tool requirements, which can be written in pyproject.toml files. So using pip to uninstall toml is essentially using it to uninstall one of its own dependencies for building packages -- not smart, and following a comment the simplest solution was just to uninstall and reinstall pip on a system level.